# Oracle SQL STATS_MODE with two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the tables listed in the image. I need to display the institution and loan type of the most used financing plan in the sale_financing table. I have tried using the stats_mode function but I have not been able to get it to work. I am supposed to only display the most used financing plan and I keep getting 3 showing up. Here is an image of the tables.

[image]

My image may not work so here are the tables:

```
financing_plan
     id
     institution
     loan_type

sale_financings
     id
     plan_id ------> foreign key linking to - financing_plan.id
```

I have tried several different ways in the Query Builder and I cannot get it to work.

Here is one :

```
SELECT
    financing_plans.institution,
    financing_plans.loan_type,
    STATS_MODE(sale_financings.plan_id) AS stats_mode_plan_id
FROM
    financing_plans
    INNER JOIN sale_financings ON financing_plans.id = 
    sale_financings.plan_id
GROUP BY
    financing_plans.institution,
    financing_plans.loan_type
```

Another:

```
SELECT
    financing_plans.institution,
    financing_plans.loan_type,
    STATS_MODE(sale_financings.plan_id) AS stats_mode_plan_id
FROM
    financing_plans
    INNER JOIN sale_financings ON financing_plans.id = 
    sale_financings.plan_id
GROUP BY
    financing_plans.institution,
    financing_plans.loan_type
HAVING
    STATS_MODE(sale_financings.plan_id) = sale_financings.plan_id
```

Comment: Please show any query that you have tried.

Comment: "the most used financing plan" what happens if there are 2 or more types of "equal top"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the use of each plan_id, then rank these (using `dense_rank()`) by the count (descending order) allows "top" and "equal top" to be shown.

```
select
      fp.institution, fp.loan_type, s.plan_count
from financing_plan fp
inner join (
      select plan_id, plan_count, dense_rank() over(order by plan_count DESC) as rnk
      from (
            select plan_id, count(id) plan_count
            from sale_financings
            Group by plan_id
           )
      ) s on fp.id = s.plan_id and s.rnk = 1
order by 
      fp.institution, fp.loan_type
;
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot, although I had to decipher what the fp was. I assumed you were abbreviating it so you didn't have to type it out. I didn't realize you named it that for easier use later on in the script. Only issue I ran into is that I needed to add a GROUP BY sale_financings.plan_id after the from sale_financings in the middle inside the inner join. Thanks.

Comment: I missed the necessary `group by` clause. Sorry. I have now added it above. `fp` is a table alias, something you  will want to be familiar with.